# How should print all the indices of a matrix which are the maximum number of that matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Like we can consider following matrix:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkWrY.jpg)

Now I want to display all the indices of the maximum no of the matrix and not just only one indices of the max of the matrix.

Comment: Please no screenshots, instead write the code *into* the question itself.

Comment: Include your code and a clear definition of the problem in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```python
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[2,3,2], [7,7,6], [2,7,3]])
print(mat)

max_indices = np.where(mat == np.amax(mat))
print(max_indices)

index_max = mat[max_indices]
print(index_max)
```

Output:

```
[[2 3 2]
 [7 7 6]
 [2 7 3]]
(array([1, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 1]))  # first array: x-axis, second: y-axis
[7 7 7]
```